# Somehow mod_rewrite redirects to another site when typing in a directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So while looking around how to delete trailing slashes, I modified my .htaccess to try some different sets of codes.

When I went ahead to try out the code, I went to */page/example/* but then somehow it now redirects to http://domain.com (yes, that exact website.) Even when I deleted the .htaccess file it still does it. However if I enter */page/example/index.php* it works just fine.

What I am asking is how to fix this. Do I need an extra .htaccess?

Here is the whole .htaccess file. Note I have changed the coding since then but I think that's neligible because it still redirects even when I did delete the file from the server.

```
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/website/passwd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "text"
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.php|\.html)/$  /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

The page in the directory (index.php) actually does load but is then redirected to the aforementioned website. What is also interesting that this is not done to */page/*, just */page/example/*.

Comment: did you restart apache ?

Comment: I don't know how, and when searching through my host's directories and cPanel I found no file relating to Apache (obviously, I use a webhost.)

Comment: Restarting Apache won't be necessary when changing .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem remains after you delete the .htaccess file, this file cannot be the problem. You probably have a second .htaccess file in the /page/example directory. Either that, or you got an http error page (403 or 404) that redirects.

Comment: There is no extra .htaccess file in the directory nor have I made any changes to the error pages.